# Excel sum formula but with Criteria from multiple tables and columns

Tags: excel, sum, formula, sumifs

I have 3 Sheets / Tables in my Excel...

---

**Table 1 (Master Stock):**

[image]

---

**Table 2 (SubLocation Rules):**

[image]

---

**Table 3 (Product Stock Summarize):**

[image]

---

The goal in table 3 is **To sum the Product Stock on Table 1 but with SubLocation Rules on table 2**.

We can see for example:

- Product4 has 0 stock in all location because its stock in location C003 is not included in SubLocation Rules. So, it should not be summed into table 3.
- Product1 only has 5 stocks in Location A even though it has 9 more in Location A005. But since A005 is not allowed, we don't sum A005 into final Stock in table 3.
- Product2 has zero stock in Location C because Location C004 is not allowed by the rules.

I can use SumIfs just to calculate with ProductName and Location as the Criteria. But I'm struggling to calculate with extra table as criteria.

Any idea to calculate the Stock with Location and SubLocation criteria? (i don't use VBA macro in this case, just pure excel formula)

Thank You....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SUMIFS`, use `FILTER`. That way you can filter based on whether Location/SubLocation have a match in the SubLocation Rules table.

With `FILTER` set up, `CHOOSECOLS` to get the Stock column, and `SUM` to get the total.

```
=IFERROR(SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(master_stock,(master_stock[ProductName]=$B5)*(master_stock[Location]=F$1)*(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(master_stock[Location]&master_stock[SubLocation],sublocation_rules[Location]&sublocation_rules[SubLocation],0))))),5)),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank youuu. It works on newer version of Excel. Any suggestion for older version? The older version of Excel doesn't support all formula, for example -> FILTER()

Comment: I'm sure someone smarter and older than me will have an array formula or `SUMPRODUCT` solution. If I had to do this on an older version, I would either add a column to the Master Stock table labelling each row as Valid or Invalid. Or user Power Query to create a new table / pivot table with only valid rows.